# При использовании библиотеки JS select2 при обновлении данных на странице создается 2 select вместо одного

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, javascript-events

Проект C# asp net core. Использую jQuery v3.5.1 и BootStrap 4.

Есть select:

```
<div id="divHouse" class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="HouseId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select class="selectСhoice" id="HouseId" asp-for="HouseId" asp-items="ViewBag.GetHouses" style="width:100%"></select>
            </div>
```

На него вешаю обработчик из библиотеки  select2:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.selectСhoice').select2({
                dropdownParent: $('#divHouse'),
                placeholder: "Выберите дом",
                minimumInputLength: 1, // only start searching when the user has input 3 or more characters
                maximumInputLength: 5, // only allow terms up to 20 characters long
                language: "ru"
            });
        });
```

Проблема в том, что когда у меня обновляется какой-нибудь из select на странице рядом с прошлым селектом появляется новый с обновленными данными и остается тот что с обработчиком. Т.е. получается 2 select на одном из которых висит обработчик, со старыми данными и новый с обновленными данными, но без обработчика.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код всей страницы:

```
    <div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" id="RequestVerificationToken"
           name="RequestVerificationToken" value="@GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FamilyName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FamilyName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FamilyName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PatronymicName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="PatronymicName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PatronymicName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DateBirth" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="DateBirth" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="DateBirth" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CityId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select id="CityId" asp-for="CityId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CityId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DistrictId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="DistrictId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.DistrictId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StreetId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select id="StreetId" asp-for="StreetId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.StreetId"></select>
            </div>
            @*<div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MicroDistrictId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="MicroDistrictId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.MicroDistrictId"></select>
            </div>*@
            <div id="divHouse" class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="HouseId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select class="selectСhoice" id="HouseId" asp-for="HouseId" asp-items="ViewBag.GetHouses" style="width:100%"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Building" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Building" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Building" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Apartment" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Apartment" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Apartment" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Telephone" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Telephone" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Telephone" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PollingStationId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select id="PollingStationId" asp-for="PollingStationId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.PollingStations"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Organization" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Organization" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Organization" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FieldActivityId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="FieldActivityId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.FieldActivityId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PhoneNumberResponsible" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="PhoneNumberResponsible" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PhoneNumberResponsible" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DateRegistrationSite" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="DateRegistrationSite" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="DateRegistrationSite" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="VotingDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input id="dateVoting" asp-for="VotingDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="VotingDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Voter" class="control-label"></label>
                <input id="boolVoter" type="checkbox" asp-for="Voter" class="form-control" onchange="setDate('dateVoting')" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Qrcode" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Qrcode" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Qrcode" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UserId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="UserId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.UserId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="GroupUId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="GroupUId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.GroupUId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

<environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
</environment>

@section Scripts {

    <script>

        //Установка даты голосования
        function setDate(idObject) {

            chbox = document.getElementById('boolVoter');
            if (chbox.checked) {
                var today = new Date();
                var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
                var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
                var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
                today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
                document.getElementById(idObject).value = today;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById(idObject).value = null;
            }
        }

        // Обновление списка улиц после выбора города
        $(function () {
            $("#CityId").change(function () {
                var formData = { 'CityId': Number.parseInt($('#CityId').val()), 'Name': $('#CityId>option:selected').text()};
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:18246/api/API/searchStreets",
                    headers:
                    {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'RequestVerificationToken': $('#RequestVerificationToken').val()
                    },
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(formData),
                    success: function (data) {

                        dataFilling(data, 'idStreet', 'name', '#StreetId', '<option/>');
                    },
                    error: function (result, status, er) {
                        alert("error: " + result + " status: " + status + " er:" + er);
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        // Обновление списка домов после выбора улицы
         $(function () {
             $("#StreetId").change(function () {
                 var id = $('#StreetId').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetHouses")/' + id,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#HouseId').replaceWith(data);
                    },
                    error: function (result, status, er) {
                        alert("error: " + result + " status: " + status + " er:" + er);
                    }
                });
            });
         });

        // Обновление списка участков после выбора улицы
        $(function () {
            $("#StreetId").change(function () {
                var formData = { 'IdStreet': Number.parseInt($('#StreetId').val()), 'Name': $('#StreetId>option:selected').text()};
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:18246/api/API/searchPollingStations/street",
                    headers:
                    {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'RequestVerificationToken': $('#RequestVerificationToken').val()
                    },
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(formData),
                    success: function (data) {
                        dataFilling(data, 'idPollingStation', 'name', '#PollingStationId', '<option/>');
                    },
                    error: function (result, status, er) {
                        alert("error: " + result + " status: " + status + " er:" + er);
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        // Обновление списка участков после выбора номера дома
        $(function () {
            $("#HouseId").change(function () {
                var formData = { 'IdHouse': Number.parseInt($('#HouseId').val()), 'Name': $('#HouseId>option:selected').text()};
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:18246/api/API/searchPollingStations/house",
                    headers:
                    {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'RequestVerificationToken': $('#RequestVerificationToken').val()
                    },
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(formData),
                    success: function (data) {
                        dataFilling(data, 'idPollingStation','name', '#PollingStationId', '<option/>');                  
                    },
                    error: function (result, status, er) {
                        alert("error: " + result + " status: " + status + " er:" + er);
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        //Заполнение объекта html данными из json массива
        function dataFilling(data, nameProperty1, nameProperty2, idObject, propertyHtml) {

            var objectHtml = $(idObject);
            objectHtml.empty();

            $.each(data, function (index, dataInstance) {
                objectHtml.append($(propertyHtml,
                    {
                        value: dataInstance[nameProperty1],
                        text: dataInstance[nameProperty2]
                    }));
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.selectСhoice').select2({
                dropdownParent: $('#divHouse'),
                placeholder: "Выберите дом",
                minimumInputLength: 1, // only start searching when the user has input 3 or more characters
                maximumInputLength: 5, // only allow terms up to 20 characters long
                language: "ru"
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Для обновления списка домов есть ещё дополнительное представление:

```
@model IEnumerable<House>;

<select id="HouseId" name="Houses" class="form-control">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <option value="@item.IdHouse">@item.Name</option>
    }
</select>
```

Comment: Для чего тут метка c#?

Comment: @tym32167, проект C# asp net core и возможно есть какая-то специфика, я  не  уверен

Comment: Смотрите что у вас с бекенда приезжает, если то, что вам надо, то ваш вопрос чисто про фронтенд.

Comment: @tym32167, да с бэка вроде все норм приходит, оно и в select грузится, но почему-то не в тот